# If $Z(S_3) \leq C_{s_3}(A)=A$ and $(12) \notin Z(S_3)$, then $\sigma \in C_{s_3}(A) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an extract from dummit and foote abstract algebra page No. 51.

Here $A=\{1,(12)\}$

$C_{s_3}(A)="\text{centralizer of} ~A\ \text{in}\ S_3"=\{g\in S_3|gag^{-1}=a,~~\forall a \in A\}$

and $N_{S_3}(A)= "\text{normalizer of } A \text{ in}\ S_3"=\{g \in G|gAg^{-1}=A\}$

We are showing $C_{s_3}(A)=N_{S_3}(A)=A$

Here I can't understand [image]how the last line "The center of $ S_3$ is the identity because $Z(S_3) \leq C_{s_3}(A)=A$ and $(12) \notin Z(S_3)$ $\implies \sigma \in C_{s_3}(A)  $

Comment: $$Why\ type\ like\ this?$$

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

For all elements in $Z(S_3)$, they will commute with all elements of $S_3$, surely they will commute with all elements in $C_{S_3}(A)$, hence, $Z(S_3) \leq C_{s_3}(A)$. Just now you have computed $C_{s_3}(A)=A=\{e, (12) \}$. So we have
$$Z(S_3) \leq \{e, (12) \}$$

And we have already known $(12)\notin Z(S_3)$, hence $Z(S_3)=\{e \}$, which is trivial.

Comment: Thats okay. I am asking how this implies $\sigma \in C_{S_3}(A)$

Comment: The book shows $\sigma\in C_{S_3}(A)$ first. And then show $Z(S_3)=\{e \}$. In the book, it says "$\sigma (12)\sigma^{-1}=(12)$" do you understand this step?